# Add EventListener to Notification using titanium 3+(Android OS)

Tags: titanium

I want to add a event listener to the notification, so that i can handle other process when user come from notification.

some of my code is here...

```
  // Create the notification
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
  // icon is passed as an Android resource ID -- see Ti.App.Android.R.
  icon: Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.my_icon,
  contentTitle: 'Something Happened',
  contentText : 'Click to return to the application.',
  contentIntent: pending
});
```

// add listener to the notfication

```
notification.addEventListener('event_name',function(){});
```

here i dont know what is name of **event_name**.

If there is any other way to handle this problem,plz suggest.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'click' for the event name? That is what it usually is, I will just go and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
//CloudPush setup
CloudPush.showTrayNotification = true;
CloudPush.showAppOnTrayClick = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;

    CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
        Ti.API.info('Inside CloudPush-Callback.');
    });
    CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function (evt) {
        Ti.API.info('Inside CloudPush-trayClickLaunchedApp. Payload => ' +  evt.payload);
    });
    // Triggered when the push notifications is in the tray when the app is running
    CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function (evt) {
        Ti.API.info('Inside CloudPush-trayClickFocusedApp. Payload => ' +  evt.payload);
    });
```